# c# разделить массив на N массивов

Tags: c#

Нужно разделить массив на N массивов равного размера.
Как пытаюсь делать

```
     private void start_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] arrString = new string[100];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arrString.Length; i++)
            arrString[i] = "Индекс: [" + i + "] Значение:" + i * i;

        int arrStringCountForThread = (arrString.Length / 10);
         
        int nWorkerThreads =600;
        int nCompletionThreads = 600;
        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out nWorkerThreads, out nCompletionThreads);


        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
        {
            string[] NEWarrString = new string[arrStringCountForThread];

            // копируем из numbers с 2-го индекса 5 элементов 
            // и поместим их в массив numbers2, начиная с 0-го индекса
            Array.Copy(arrString, (i*arrStringCountForThread), NEWarrString, 0,  arrStringCountForThread);

         //   MessageBox.Show("Размер массива: " + arrStringCountForThread + " size new array: " + NEWarrString.Length);
            //Thread.Sleep(500);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(mythread1, NEWarrString);
            //  thread2.Start();
             
        }

    }



    void mythread1(object state)
    {
        string[] daysOfWeek = (string[])state;
        

        for (int i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.Length; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
          
            string pool = Convert.ToString(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
          
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => this.result.Text +=daysOfWeek[i] + "\n"));
        }

    }
```

Получаю System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "Индекс находился вне границ массива."

Comment: ваш код не компилируется, что такое `mythread1`, и зачем оно здесь?

Comment: Я лично тут не вижу ошибки. Она где-то в другом месте. Что делает с массивом поток?

Comment: @aepot, поправил первое сообщение, добавил весь код.
Есть массив, хочу обработать его к примеру в 10 потоках, для этого хочу разделить массив на 10 частей и каждому потоку передать часть

Comment: @user54353 обязательно использовать `Thread` или можно просто сделать параллельно, например с помощью `Task`?

Comment: @aepot, я хочу собрать статистику по всем зарегистрированным сайтам в интернете. Собираюсь перебрать все возможные комбинации букв символов и цифр.  Нужно получить максимум потоков. Что с этим справиться лучше?
Спасибо

Comment: @user54353 Мой алгоритм с этим легко справиться. В мой ответ нужно прикручивать параллельную реализацию обработки подмассивов (и каким способом это сделать, например, `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel`, `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, `System.Threading.Thread` или как-либо ещё)?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: @Kromster, в вопросе полный код

Comment: @Kromster единственное, что тут не описано, это чёткие требования к параллелизму, а так всё вполне понятно. Да, конечно, лучше расписать, но, по моему мнению, всё понятно.

Comment: @return дело не столько в том что нужно добавить, а и в том что нужно убрать лишнего из вопроса.

Comment: @Kromster это да, тут лучше конкретизировать.

Comment: В вопросе XY-проблема. Автор дописал важную деталь совершенно случайно - _Собираюсь перебрать все возможные комбинации букв символов и цифр._ Это в корне меняет подход к параллелизму, на основе чего я и дал ниже ответ.

Comment: В дотнете есть специальные средства для разбиения источников данных (массивов) на разделы: [Partitioner.Create](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create?view=netcore-3.1). Также смотрите [How to: Speed Up Small Loop Bodies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-speed-up-small-loop-bodies) с примером его использования

Comment: Отметьте принятым наиболее полезный ответ, или оба бесполезные?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Реализация</sub>

```
static void SplitSpan<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> buffer, Span<Range> ranges, out Range remaining)
{
    remaining = default;

    var segLen = buffer.Length / ranges.Length; // segment length

    remaining = (segLen * ranges.Length)..;

    var segOff = 0; // segment offset

    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.Length; i++)
        ranges[i] = segOff..(segOff += segLen);
}
```

<sub>Использование</sub>

```
static void Main()
{
    var buf = new[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; // buffer
    var rngs = new Range[3]; // ranges
    SplitSpan<int>(buf, rngs, out var rem); // remaining

    for (var i = 0; i < rngs.Length; i++)
        PrintSpan<int>($"Subspan #{i + 1}: ", buf[rngs[i]]);

    PrintSpan<int>("Remaining: ", buf[rem]);
}
// don't use in your project
static void PrintSpan<T>(string prefix, ReadOnlySpan<T> buffer)
{
    Console.Write(prefix);

    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(buffer[i].ToString());
        Console.Write(' ');
    }

    if (!buffer.IsEmpty) Console.WriteLine(buffer[^1].ToString());
}
```

<sub>Вывод</sub>

```js
Subspan #1: 0 1 2
Subspan #2: 3 4 5
Subspan #3: 6 7 8
Remaining: 9
```

<sup>**Примечание.** Комментарии, оставленные мной в коде, лучше убрать.</sup>

В методе `SplitSpan` сосредоточена вся реализация алгоритма. Аргумент `buffer` – входной массив (тип `Span<T>`/`ReadOnlySpan<T>` – это оптимизированная версия классических массивов), `ranges` – массив диапазонов итоговых подмассивов, `remaining` – то, что осталось. Чтобы получить подмассив нужно использовать вот такой код: `buffer[ranges[i]]`, где `i` – индекс подмассива.

Меня количество диапазонов вы меняете размер итоговых подмассивов. Чтобы вычислить кол-во диапазонов, нужно длину массива поделить на длину подмассива.

Зачем нужны диапазоны? Почему сразу не преобразовать в массив? Дело в том, что если вы работаете с `Span<T>`/`Memory<T>`/`T[]`, то в результате вы хотите получить объект этого типа, а если вы получаете его сразу, то пропадает совместимость между остальными. `Span<T>` – ссылка + длина, `Memory<T>` – ссылка на источник данных + стартовый индекс + длина, `T[]` – реализован внутри CLR. Поэтому диапазон является предпочтительной формой возврата, да и хранить его куда проще, ведь это 2 индекса, а в случае с возвратом готового подмассива вам придётся хранить в пустую скопированные данные.

Comment: Не удалось найти тип или имя пространства имен "Range" (возможно, отсутствует директива using или ссылка на сборку

Comment: @user54353 вы под что пишите? если под .NET Framework, у меня для вас плохие новости. Скоро его свернут и выйдет единый .NET 5 на основе .NET Core (в нём есть тип `System.Range`), поэтому если вы только начали писать код, я настоятельно рекомендую его закопипастить, только под .NET Core.

Comment: @user54353 [System.Range (официальная документация, на английском)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=netcore-3.1), [.NET 5 (официальный блог компани Microsoft на Habr)](https://habr.com/ru/company/microsoft/blog/508622/), [Справка о переносе кода с .NET Framework на .NET Core (официальная документация)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/porting/).

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть проблема с многопоточностью. Если где-то возникнет исключение, вы его не увидите, потому что никак не ожидаете завершения задач.

Так же, на данный момент C# позволяет достаточно просто работать с многопоточностью и асинхронностью с помощью `async/await` и `Task`.

> я хочу собрать статистику по всем зарегистрированным сайтам в интернете. Собираюсь перебрать все возможные комбинации букв символов и цифр. Нужно получить максимум потоков. Что с этим справиться лучше?

Я бы сделал примерно так:

```csharp
private async void start_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(p => result.Text += p);
    try
    {
        string[] arrString = new string[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrString.Length; i++)
            arrString[i] = "Индекс: [" + i + "] Значение:" + i * i;

        int maxConcurrency = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2; // сколько одновременно может работать потоков
        using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency)) 
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (string s in arrString)
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // ждать, если максимальное количество уже работает, пока потоков не станет меньше

                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessString(s, progress, semaphore))); // запуск CPU-bound операции
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // ждать завершения всех
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}


private void ProcessString(string dayOfWeek, IProgress<string> progress, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    try
    {
        progress.Report(dayOfWeek + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Изучите разницу между CPU-зависимыми и I/O-зависимыми операциями [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

Если как вы указали в комментариях, у вас I/O операция, то есть обращение по сети, то она может выглядеть так

```csharp
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

private async Task ProcessPage(string url, IProgress<string> progress, SemaphoreSlim semaphore)
{
    try
    {
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        string result = DoSomething(html); // обработка полученной страницы
        progress.Report(result);
    } 
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

```csharp
using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxConcurrency)) 
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    foreach (string url in urls)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        
        tasks.Add(ProcessPage(url, progress, semaphore)); // запуск I/O-bound операции
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

*Обратите внимание, ответы от запущенных задач могут возвращаться не в том порядке, в каком задачи были запущены.*

Comment: `Task.Run` использует по умолчанию пул потоков, потому вам семафор тут не нужен - у вас всё равно не будет потоков больше, чем в пуле. Асинхронные I/O операции нет смысла сопоставлять с количеством потоков, так сами по себе асинхронные операции не тратят поток, то есть во втором варианте семафор опять не нужен. Если же операция синхронная, то для такого есть `Parallel.For`.

Comment: @aepot, "int maxConcurrency = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2; // сколько одновременно может работать потоков"
Environment.ProcessorCount = 4, выходит я могу использовать максимум 8 потоков?

Comment: @user54353 вы можете указать числом столько, сколько вам нужно просто числом. Просто принято не запускать огромную кучу задач одновременно, чтобы не нагружать процессор излишним количеством переключений между задачами. Поэтому я продемонстрировал рекомендацию привязаться к числу логических процессоров.